# 1970s live action Spider-Man TV series fancy dress/costume party episode

Tags: marvel, tv, episode-identification, spider-man

Did this happen or am I suffering from the Mandela Effect?

I remember watching a live action episode of The Amazing Spider-Man in the late 1970s and Peter Parker was getting ready to go to a fancy dress party. (A costume party in the USA)

His aunt had made him a costume (maybe a cavalier but I'm not sure) and he tried it and was impressed when he looked in his wardrobe mirror.

Disaster strikes! He bends  and the trousers split. In desperation  he actually goes dressed as Spidey.

I've looked at the [episodes listed](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Amazing_Spider-Man_(TV_series)), but there's not enough detail given

Comment: For anyone confused (as I was), British English “fancy dress party” = American English “costume party”.

Comment: Huh. I've never seen an American party involving fancy dress being called a "costume party", and thought the joke went the other direction. :-D

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sounds like you're thinking of *The Amazing Spider-Man* S01E04, "[Night of the Clones](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0511078/)" (1978).

From IMDB:

> Peter goes and takes photos of a scientist who has perfected the art of cloning, cloning a frog. At the same time, a member of a scientific group who gives scientific awards is killed. And the police get a of description of the person who did it and it's the scientist. But how could have been there when he was at the demonstration. Later another attempt is made on another member of the group but Spiderman saves her, but the woman refuses to implicate the scientist who called her to the meeting. Peter suspects that the motive is that the group refuses to honor the scientist's work. So he goes to see the head of the group who confirms Peter's suspicions that they refuse to honor him because they didn't want the scientist to clone a man which he did; himself. Who in turn after getting a sample of Spiderman's DNA clones him.

From [a review](http://lifebetweenframes.blogspot.com/2019/04/the-amazing-spider-man-1977-night-of.html) of the episode:

> In the midst of all this, there's a minor "Peter Parker is just a regular, cash-strapped guy" subplot where **Jameson assigns Peter to cover the Tovald committee's costume party. Since Jameson won't cover the price of a costume, Peter enlists the help of his elderly Aunt May, who was played by Jeff Donnell in the TV movie that started this series but is played in this episode by Irene Tedrow. May suggests a Frankenstein's Monster costume, but rules it out because Peter can't stand the sight of blood. There is his late uncle Max's swashbuckling Errol Flynn costume...** Wait a minute, uncle Max? Why would this show change his uncle's name from Ben to Max? Regardless, **that costume rips when Peter tries it on.**
>
> **Of course, Peter has a great costume already in his closet. Can you guess what he wears to the party?**

You can view the scene in question at the 39.06 mark in the video below.

Comment: “Oh no! The trousers ripped! If only I didn’t have the proportionate redonkulous butt of a spider!”